# How to upload Multipart Image in rails api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My requirement is to upload an image in Multi Part format in rails.How i can achieved this in rails.

Comment: did it work ???

Comment: not yet it is not working.
 TypeError (no implicit conversion of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String):

Comment: Please show the code you have tried.

Comment: Perameters
"---------<ActionController::Parameters {\"image\"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f4274b25cb0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170508-4-1brqg3p.jpg>, @original_filename=\"profile.jpg\", @content_type=\"image/jpg\", @headers=\"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\\\"image\\\"; filename=\\\"profile.jpg\\\"\\r\\nContent-Type: image/jpg\\r\\n\">, \"controller\"=>\"v1/users\", \"action\"=>\"upload_image\", \"format\"=>\"json\"} permitted: false>"

Comment: method code

     @filename = File.new(params[:image], "rb")
     File.open(@filename, "wb") do |file|
       file.write(@filename.read)
     end
     image = File.open(@filename)

Comment: Okay 
please find my method code
def upload_image
     @filename = File.new(params[:image], "rb")
     File.open(@filename, "wb") do |file|
       file.write(@filename.read)
     end
 end

Comment: Please edit your question with your code, it's unreadable in the comments.

Comment: please see this https://github.com/pluralsight/guides/blob/master/published/ruby-ruby-on-rails/handling-file-upload-using-ruby-on-rails-5-api/article.md